# stack inside colum in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Can I use Stack inside Column widget?

```
Container(child: Column(children: 
[
Text('This is going to hit'),
Stack(children: [Image.asset('picture.png'),]),
Text(' lorem ipsum dolor si amet consecture')
])
]))
```

```
SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                               Stack(
                  clipBehavior: Clip.none,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                                    ]),
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Text(
                              'heyyyyyy.'),
                          Container(
                            height: 300,
                            width: double.infinity,
                            child: Stack(
                              clipBehavior: Clip.none,
                              children: [
                                Positioned(
                                  top: 4,
                                  left: -25,
                                  right: -25,
                                  child: Image.asset('assets/be11.png'),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 5,
                          ),
                          Text(Data.loremIpsum),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Here is my code. Now the image is fit into the white container area. I want to pop it out of the container.

Image border is not necessary. When I increase values of Positioned widget of image, it doesn't pop out of the below container border.

Comment: If is just an image that you want to add, you can enter the the image inside a container then give to it white borders and increase its width with rounder corners.

Comment: the border is out of the layout. so it is better to user in stack or not?

Comment: Do you get any error while using this snippet?

Comment: nope. I just want that poping effect

Comment: Not sure about the effect, can you provide details about effect.

Comment: I understand in that case is fine to do it, but I recommend you to add one stack then the children would be, a white container with round border, text positioned at the top, then the image poping up, finally the description text at the bottom.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I mean, the image should be pop out of the white card area. it should be like out of the container. Just shown in the image.

Comment: @WilsonToribio can you show me in code. I just want to show the above whole layout. code should be output the above image

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how you can do it, this is for you to have an idea then you can adjust it as you needed:

```
Scaffold(
        body: Column(
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
          child: Container(
            width: 200,
            height: 280,
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                Center(
                  child: Container(
                    width: 180,
                    height: 280,
                    color: Colors.green,
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                    top: 5,
                    left: 15,
                    child: SizedBox(
                      width: 180,
                      child: Text(
                          'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been ', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),),
                    )),

                Positioned(
                  top: 45,
                  child: Container(

                    width: 200,
                    height: 100,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.grey
                    ),

                  ),
                ),

                Positioned(
                    top: 150,
                    left: 15,
                    child: SizedBox(
                      width: 180,
                      child: Text(
                        'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been ', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),),
                    )),

              ],
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    ))
```

Comment: I have added my code and edited the question

Answer (score 0):

```
   ///No need to add stack widget you can make this UI like this way hope this will work for you thankyou
    
         import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
            
            class Task extends StatefulWidget {
              const Task({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
            
              @override
              _TaskState createState() => _TaskState();
            }
            
            class _TaskState extends State<Task> {
              @override
              Widget build(BuildContext context) {
                return Scaffold(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                    body: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 50.0, left: 10, right: 10),
                      child: Container(
                        color: Colors.blue[100],
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30.0, left: 10, right: 10),
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Row(
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  'News',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.blue,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: 5,
                                ),
                                CircleAvatar(
                                    radius: 8,
                                    child: Icon(
                                      Icons.arrow_forward_outlined,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      size: 10,
                                    ))
                              ],
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 10,
                            ),
                            Card(
                              elevation: 5,
                              child: Container(
                                height: 700,
                                child: Column(
                                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                    children: [
                                      Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                                        child: Text(
                                          'The marian uprising missionaries dedicated community is coming into existence',
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.blue,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                              fontSize: 18),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      Card(
                                          shape: OutlineInputBorder(
                                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white)),
                                          elevation: 10,
                                          child: Padding(
                                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                            child: Container(
                                              height: 200,
                                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                  shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                                  image: DecorationImage(
                                                      image: NetworkImage(
                                                        'https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/colorful-wavy-object-picture-id1198272365?s=612x612',
                                                      ),
                                                      fit: BoxFit.cover)),
                                            ),
                                          )),
                                      Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                                        child: Text(
                                          "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummied text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived five centuries and the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum",
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.blue,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      )
                                    ]),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ));
              }
            }
```

Comment: no bro. this is not working.

Comment: I want center image should be pop out of the text holding container. just like the image